# Servidor não inicia no ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

O meu servidor não inicia no ruby. Alguém poderia me ajudar a entender o porquê?

```
$ rails server
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:287:in `block in verify_gemfile_dependencies_are_found!': Could not find gem 'sqlite3 (~> 1.4) x64-mingw32' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile. (Bundler::GemNotFound)
        from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:255:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:255:in `verify_gemfile_dependencies_are_found!'
        from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:49:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:22:in `resolve'
        from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:258:in `resolve'
        from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:170:in `specs'
        from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:237:in `specs_for'
        from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:226:in `requested_specs'
        from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:108:in `block in definition_method'
        from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:20:in `setup'
        from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler.rb:107:in `setup'
        from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/setup.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/Users/robson/Desktop/rub/prazomad/config/boot.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:3:in `require_relative'
        from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro, verifique o `Gemfile` na raiz da sua aplicação e veja se ele está especificando a *gem* corretamente:

```
gem 'sqlite3 (~> 1.4)'
```

Depois, tente rodar o comando `bundle install` no terminal para instalar as *gems* que porventura estejam faltando, pode ser esse o caso.

Comment: boa noite tentei fazer e não consegui olha na mensagem o print